# How to attach bootchart.SVG file?

Tags: support

I have posted a [question on **Slow Boot**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/737319/ubuntu-booting-too-slow-after-dual-boot-kali) which requires **bootchart.svg** file to be attached for better understanding of the problem.

When I try to attach it, I get this:

[image]

Currently I have uploaded it to my Google Drive and attached the link in my post

Is there any other better way I can attach this file??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Stackexchange do not support svg files obviously (unfortunately).

Uploading the image somewhere else (Google Drive, Dropbox) is one solution (but not much future-proof one).

The other is to convert the image to some supported format. You can simply do that on your Ubuntu command-line for example using

```
convert bootchart.{svg,png}
```

If you are interested in having this working, you can fill a feature request on [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks :-) , But converting svg to png reduces the quality of image :(

Comment: It certainly does. But it also makes the image working everywhere, even on ancient IE's. But it should not be problem today. For that there are other possibilities as I mentioned.